# Backwards compatibility fallback for `translateY`

Tags: html, css

I have a div, that needs to be centered vertically.

Have achieved that with `translateY`.

```
div {
    position: absolute; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
    top: 55%; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -moz-transform: translateY(-50%); -o-transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Now in browsers that don't support `transform`, I would like to have a different value for `top` or set `top: 0;` and add a `margin-top`.

Is it possible to do this?

---

Or is there a better way to center vertically thats more supported?

Comment: Do you need a solution for IE8? Transform is supported pretty well: https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: @RolandStarke Well Opera Mini (especially—primarily it'll be used on mobile), Opera and Firefox are more of a concern.

Comment: Firefox should be supported. Don't forget to remove the `-webkit-` prefix. Opera mini idk.

Comment: @RolandStarke Why remove `-webkit-` caniuse.com says certain browsers need it?

Comment: Yes sry, then i mean add multiple rules with different prefixes. Else your rule will only work in Chrome.

Comment: Unless your div is fixed height, you would probably need a js fallback for browsers that can't handle translate